# Why does Alexa SDK throw an error when migrating from Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to migrate my action form Dialogflow, and the most important thing is the intent schema. But after uploading the .json file, the error `Intent name must not be empty. Error code: MissingIntentName` is thrown. Here is Intent schema.json

```
 {
"intents": [
{
  "intent": "SelectedSubjectsYes"
},
{
  "intent": "UserIsOk",
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "okslot",
      "type": "OK"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "intent": "SelectedSubjectsNo"
},
{
  "intent": "UserIsNotOk",
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "not_okslot",
      "type": "NOT_OK"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "intent": "DefaultWelcomeIntent"
},
{
  "intent": "HowAreYou?"
},
{
  "intent": "SelectedSubjects",
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "subjectslot",
      "type": "SUBJECT"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

I've in no way edited it, so why the error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON structure for interaction model is sightly different. This is how it should look now.

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "Your invocation name",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "SelectedSubjectsYes",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "provide sample for SelectedSubjectsYes intent",
                        "sample for SelectedSubjectsYes intent"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserIsOk",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "okslot",
                            "type": "OK"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "provide other samples for UserIsOk",
                        "I'm {okslot}",
                        "{okslot}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "SelectedSubjectsNo",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "provide sample for SelectedSubjectsNo intent",
                        "sample for SelectedSubjectsNo intent"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserIsNotOk",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "not_okslot",
                            "type": "NOT_OK"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "provide other samples for UserIsNotOk",
                        "i'm {not_okslot}",
                        "{not_okslot}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "HowAreYou?",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "provide sample for HowAreYou intent",
                        "sample for HowAreYou intent"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "SelectedSubjects",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "subjectslot",
                            "type": "SUBJECT"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "provide other samples for SelectedSubjects",
                        "i choose {subjectslot}"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "OK",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "ok"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "yes"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "NOT_OK",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "not ok"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "nope"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "SUBJECT",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "Physics"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "Biology"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than converting from Dialog flow, it's pretty easy to design one in Alexa skill builder. Also, it is recommended to use predefined `AMAZON.YesIntent` and `AMAZON.NoIntent` for *"yes"* or *"no"* utterances.